How to scrape Amcharts interactive data using R
I'm trying to retrieve data from the following link but I've noticed that the data is in an interactive Amcharts 1.1.
I can't find the best parameters for the GET or POST method. I think the website is using another process to post the data.
Would anyone be able to offer some insights? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(XML)
url <- 'https://live.euronext.com/en/product/equities/FR0004040608-XPAR'

page <- read_html(url)

class(page)
# "xml_document" "xml_node" 

xml_child(page, 2)
# {html_node}
# <body class="layout-no-sidebars path-product">
# [1] <a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable skip-link">\n   ...
# [2] <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-T ...
# ....
# [20] <script src="/sites/default/files/js/optimized/js_gcfptZrWxdKuaT414lrcjk ...


> page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="price-chart"]')%>% html_text()
# character(0)

page %>% html_nodes("script")%>% html_text()

page %>% html_nodes("noscript")%>% html_text()
# [1] "form.antibot * :not(.antibot-message) { display: none !important; }"
# [2] ""  


Image of the dev tools part




You have successfully identified the data source, it looks bit cryptic as it actually is encrypted (or "encrypted", at least not just base64 encoded).
Though ajax_secure_dataFilter(), function that preprocess chart data, is also callable in browser session. So if we choose a lazy route and add chromote to this mix, we can point it to the site so it would first load all JavaScript requirements for us, we can then create a small js helper function that would fetch json within a Chrome session and calls ajax_secure_dataFilter() on fetched chart data.
Finally, we can call that js function with any chart data endpoint from R, get decoded JSON as a list of lists and wrangle it into a flat frame.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(chromote)
library(stringr)

url_ <- "https://live.euronext.com/en/product/equities/FR0004040608-XPAR"
chart_max <- str_glue("https://live.euronext.com/en/intraday_chart/getChartData/{basename(url_)}/max")

b <- ChromoteSession$new()
{
  b$Page$navigate("https://live.euronext.com/en/product/equities/FR0004040608-XPAR")
  b$Page$loadEventFired()
} 
#> $timestamp
#> [1] 522961.4

# create js function that fetches chart data and passes it though ajax_secure_dataFilter() 
b$Runtime$evaluate("function fetch_chart_data(url) {return fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(json => ajax_secure_dataFilter(json, 'json', false))}")
#> $result
#> $result$type
#> [1] "undefined"

# call it with chart data url
chart_data <- b$Runtime$evaluate(str_glue('fetch_chart_data("{chart_max}")'), awaitPromise = TRUE, returnByValue = TRUE)$result$value
head(chart_data, n = 3) |> str()
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ time  : chr "1999-09-01 02:00"
#>   ..$ price : num 9.7
#>   ..$ volume: int 25810
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ time  : chr "1999-09-02 02:00"
#>   ..$ price : num 9.75
#>   ..$ volume: int 17430
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ time  : chr "1999-09-03 02:00"
#>   ..$ price : num 9.85
#>   ..$ volume: int 28270

# list to frame, parse date/time
chart_data_df <- 
  chart_data |>
  bind_rows(chart_data) |>
  mutate(time = lubridate::ymd_hm(time))

Result:
chart_data_df
#> # A tibble: 12,480 × 3
#>    time                price volume
#>    <dttm>              <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 1999-09-01 02:00:00  9.7   25810
#>  2 1999-09-02 02:00:00  9.75  17430
#>  3 1999-09-03 02:00:00  9.85  28270
#>  4 1999-09-06 02:00:00 10.1   57750
#>  5 1999-09-07 02:00:00 10.2   29830
#>  6 1999-09-08 02:00:00 10.0   13700
#>  7 1999-09-09 02:00:00 10.1   17560
#>  8 1999-09-10 02:00:00 10.2    7290
#>  9 1999-09-13 02:00:00 10.2   10040
#> 10 1999-09-14 02:00:00 10.2   12220
#> # ℹ 12,470 more rows

ggplot(chart_data_df, aes(x = time, y = price)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = "price")) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "5 years") +
  theme_minimal()


Created on 2024-05-28 with reprex v2.1.0
